# Angular-Material Datepicker: control.registerOnChange is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I don't understand this error.  I'm trying to use the `mat-datepicker` with `MomentJS` exactly as shown in [the examples](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples), but I cannot get rid of this error.

My component code looks like this:

```
import { Component,
         Input,
         OnInit }    from '@angular/core';
import { TimeRange, TimeRanges } from "./time-range-selector.constants";
import * as moment from 'moment';
import {FormControl} from "@angular/forms";


@Component({
  selector: 'time-range-selector',
  templateUrl: './time-range-selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./time-range-selector.component.scss']
})
export class TimeRangeSelectorComponent implements OnInit {

  private _timeRange: TimeRange;
  public timeRanges: {} = TimeRanges;


  public startDate: FormControl = new FormControl(moment([2017, 0, 1]));

  public endDate: FormControl = new FormControl(moment([2017, 0, 2]));

  public get selectedTimeRange(): TimeRange {
    return this._timeRange;
  }

  @Input()
  public set selectedTimeRange(range: TimeRange) {
    this._timeRange = range;
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

and my markup like this:

```
<div class="time-range-selector">

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Time Range">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let timeRange of timeRanges" [value]="timeRange.value">
        {{ timeRange.label }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <!-- start date -->
  <mat-form-field *ngIf="true">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="startDate" placeholder="Choose a date" [formControl]="startDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="endDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #startDate></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>

  <!-- end date -->
  <mat-form-field *ngIf="true">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="endDate" placeholder="Choose a date" [formControl]="endDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="endDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #endDate></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>


</div>
```

The console output says the error occurs at the line beginning `<input matInput [matDatepicker]="startDate"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your template variables for the `<mat-datepicker>` elements have the same name as the `[formControl]` bindings, which is causing issues (it looks like Angular favors the template variable over a variable declared in the component) when attempting to create a FormControl object. This fixes your issue:

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="true">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="endDatePicker" placeholder="Choose a date" [formControl]="endDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="endDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #endDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is derived from your `[matDatepicker] = "startDate"` and `[matDatepicker] = "endDate"`. Referencing the date picker with the same name of the FormControl is an issue. Update your code to something like the following.

```
 <!-- start date -->
  <mat-form-field *ngIf="true">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Choose a date" [formControl]="startDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>

  <!-- end date -->
  <mat-form-field *ngIf="true">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="Choose a date" [formControl]="endDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```